# When a checkbox is checked using javascript, state is not reflected on UI

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox in HTML UI that is informational (i.e. user cannot change it. Used onclick="return false;" to achieve this.). This checkbox is checked when a selection is made in another field (A JSONArray returned from back end and one of the entries selected by user). If the selected entry has one of the fields, say 'xxxField', is set to value 'XXX' then the checkbox needs to be checked.

`<input id="xxxEntity" type="checkbox"  onclick="return false;"  />`

Following is the javascript function that operate on this checkbox

```
    function enableXXXEntityType(entityJs){
        var entity = JSON.parse(entityJs);
        var name = entity.name;
        var xxxType = entity.xxxField;

        var typeElm = document.getElementById('xxxEntity');
        if("XXX" === xxxType){
            typeElm.checked=true;
            alert(typeElm.checked);
        }else{
            typeElm.checked=false;
        }
    }
```

The issue is when function is executed; it sets the checkbox (checked=true) but this is not reflected on UI. Checkbox continues to show as unchecked. Alert in the function shows true.
If I submit the form, checkbox value is correctly persisted and if I open the entity in view mode, I can see the checkbox 'xxxEntity' checked.

I am not sure what is the issue here.

I tried setting attribute "checked" set to "true" as well (typeElm.setAttribute("checked","true")), but that as well didn't solve the problem.

I have verified the behavior on Chrome and Edge and it is same, so i do not think it is browser specific.

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
RM

PS: I have tried searching on stackOverflow but could not find this problem. There are multiple questions relating to issues with checking checkbox state, but not related to state not reflecting on UI. If I have missed any existing answered question, please forgive me and point me to the question.

---

Edit: More details

Looks like following code is hiding the element that I am trying to update through javascript.

```
    <div id="inlineSearchResultPanel" class="searchEntryFloatingPanel">
            <table id="inlineSearhResultTable" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            </table>
    </div>
```

Corresponding CSS

```
.searchEntryFloatingPanel{
    width: 40%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 30% ;
    max-height: 600px;
    display: none;
    background-color: grey;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

In primary JS function that is triggered after search data is returned. It adds rows in the "inlineSearhResultTable" table. Once user clicks on any row, a JSON object is prepared with data of that row and passed to the first function mentioned in the problem.

When I moved the search div to a place that is after my checkbox that I want to update, problem seems to have resolved.

While this problem is solved... I am not very clear on why div with z-index=1 will block/hide checkbox from being displayed correctly.

Point to note is that I am hiding the div the moment user clicks on any row from the search table. See code below....

```
    function selectInlineSearchRow(row, callBack){

        var resultTbl = document.getElementById("inlineSearhResultTable");
        var selectedRow = resultTbl.rows[row];
        var selectedEntity = "{";

        var cellArr = selectedRow.cells;
        var firstRow = true;
        for(var i=0;i<cellArr.length;i++){
            selectedEntity += (firstRow===true?"":", ")+"\""+cellArr[i].getAttribute("id")+"\" : \""+cellArr[i].innerText+"\"";
            firstRow=false;
        }

        selectedEntity += "}";

        document.getElementById("inlineSearchResultPanel").style.display="none";

        callBack(selectedEntity);
    }
```

So not sure why the required checkbox is not displayed correctly when I change it's state through JS.

Comment: It is working as expected. The checkbox is shown as ticked. Also post your css code. Are you using any CSS library?

Comment: Hi Junaid, I am not using any css specifically for this checkbox. Its plain HTML and JavaScript.
As I mentioned in the problem statement, state change is persisted, that means value is passed to back end but somehow it is not reflected on UI. Thanks...

Comment: could you add some more code which is after this function call?